# JMeter load testing with JUnit from Selenium IDE

Tags: junit, jmeter, selenium-ide

I have problem with JMeter not picking up my JUnit test.
What I did:

- got JMeter and extracted
- created JUnit test through Selenium IDE and exported as JUnit4(WebDriver)
- try that test runs when executed (in IntelliJ)
- created JAR of the class file
- placed JAR into jmeter.home/lib/junit
- started jmeter
- created new thread
- added new sampler for JUnit request

However when I check "Classname" drop down my test is not listed there.
Does anyone know why test is not recognised by JMeter?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/18350556/2586371 solves your problem.

Comment: @BobMeliev thanx for the try but after 2 years few things changed and I do not need this anymore...

Comment: Anyway maybe it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

check whether scripts exported using junit4. 
If yes, then select "search for junit4 annotations" check box. surely it will display.

Answer (score -1):

After creating Junit jar file . Place the jar file in the
   `jmeter.home\lib` not in `jmeter.home/lib/junit`.
   After that Restart Jmeter. 
   Now add thread group to jmeter and Junit Request sampler.
   Observe that the Classname apperas in the drop down list

Comment: Please read http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf