# Running Selenium scripts with JMeter

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests, jmeter

I have Selenium automation scripts ready with functional flow, now I want to integrate those scripts with JMeter for load-testing.
Is that possible?
If so how to integrate both?

My first aim is to run the automation script using selenium than run those scripts in jmeter for load or performance testing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Below are possible ways to run Selenium test-cases from JMeter:

- using [JUnit Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request);
- using [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler);
- using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) + [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/).

## JUnit Request Sampler

Running Selenium tests this way maybe useful if you want to re-use already automated (Java) Selenium scenarios instead of re-writing JS-scripts for [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/).

#### Selenium RC

---

1. Prepare Selenium test project and setup.

   1.1. Download Selenium Java client libraries and put `selenium-java-${version}.jar` to JMeter classpath, e.g. `%JMETER_HOME%/lib/`.
   1.2. Selenium server should be up and listening:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-${version}.jar
   ```

   1.3. Export Selenium test-plan as .jar and save it to `%JMETER_HOME%/lib/junit/`.

   **NOTE:** Your test class should extend `TestCase` or `SeleneseTestCase` to allow JMeter pick up this test plan, test case's name **should start with "test"**).
   **NOTE:** By default `SeleneseTestCase` extends JUnit 3.x `TestCase`, also `SeleneseTestCase` expects external Selenium server to be running.
2. Configure [JUnit Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.pdf)

   2.1. In JMeter test-plan add [JUnit Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request).
   Set `Class Name` according to one from the Selenium test plan.
   Set `Test Method` to test that is about to run.
   Leave other parameters by default.

   [image]

   **JUnit 3.x vs. 4.x**
    JUnit Request Sampler can process both JUnit3- and JUnit4-style classes and methods. To set Sampler to search for JUnit 4 tests (`@Test` annotations) check `Search for Junit4 annotations (instead of JUnit 3)` checkbox in settings above.
    The following JUnit4 annotations are recognized:

   > @Test - used to find test methods and classes. The "expected" and "timeout" attributes are supported.
   >   @Before - treated the same as setUp() in JUnit3
   >   @After - treated the same as tearDown() in JUnit3
   >   @BeforeClass, @AfterClass - treated as test methods so they can be run independently as required
3. You are ready to start your Selenium test with JMeter.

Java code for JUnit Request sampler:

**JUnit 3.x**

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class selenium extends SeleneseTestCase {

    private static Selenium selenium;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com/");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.windowMaximize();
    }

    public void testSelenium() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", selenium.getTitle());
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.close();
    }
}
```

**JUnit 4.x**

Test script written in JUnit 4 uses JUnit annotations:

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class selenium extends SeleneseTestCase {

    private static Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.com/");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.windowMaximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelenium() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", selenium.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

#### Selenium WebDriver

---

This case is an alternative to [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) mentioned in another answer below.

**Prerequisites**

The only difference with Selenium RC case is Selenium setup preparation:

1.1. Download and put `selenium-server-standalone-${version}.jar` to JMeter classpath, e.g. `%JMETER_HOME%/lib/`.
**NOTE:** There is no need to start the Selenium server.

All the other steps are the same as in the scenario described above.

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class selenium extends TestCase {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelenium() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

---

**Upd.**

Another good points and step-by-step guides to use Selenium + JUnit + JMeter bundle:

- [Integrating Selenium with JMeter for Load Testing](http://www.anzaan.com/2012/07/integrating-selenium-with-jmeter-for-application-load-testing/)
- [Integrating Jmeter with Selenium Code](https://intensetesting.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/integrating-jmeter-with-selenium-code/)
- [Performance testing with Selenium and JMeter](http://blog.xebia.com/2012/11/18/performance-testing-with-selenium-and-jmeter/)
- [Running Selenium tests under JMeter](http://testautomation.blog.com/2013/09/20/running-selenium-tests-under-jmeter/)
- [How to integrate a JUnit4 – Webdriver test into JMeter](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/03/how-to-integrate-a-junit4-webdriver-test-into-jmeter/)

---

## BeanShell Sampler

In this case selenium test-scenario is executed directly in JMeter's [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler).

1. Selenium setup preparation is completely identical to described above cases: download Selenium libraries, put to JMeter classpath, start Selenium server (in case of Selenium RC).
2. Put your selenium test-scenario into BeanShell Sampler:

[image]

#### Selenium RC

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Boolean result = true;

try {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://www.google.com/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.windowMaximize();

    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");  

    if (!selenium.isTextPresent("Google")) result = false;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    IsSuccess = false;
    ResponseCode = "500";
    ResponseMessage = ex.getMessage();
} finally {
    selenium.stop();
}

IsSuccess = result;
return result;
```

#### Selenium WebDriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

Boolean result = true;

try {
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

    if (!driver.getTitle().contains("Google")) result = false;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    IsSuccess = false;
    ResponseCode = "500";
    ResponseMessage = ex.getMessage();
} finally {
    driver.quit();
}

IsSuccess = result;
return result;
```

---

## JSR223 Sampler + Groovy

In this case selenium test-scenario is executed via [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) + [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/).
For [performance considerations](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) this approach seems to be more preferable than using BeanShell Sampler described above.

1. Selenium setup preparation is completely identical to described above cases: download Selenium libraries, put to JMeter classpath, start Selenium server (in case of Selenium RC).
2. **Add Groovy support for JSR223 Sampler:**

   2.1. [download latest Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html) binary distribution;
   2.2. copy `groovy-all-${VERSION}.jar` from “embeddable” folder of distribution and drop it to `%JMETER_HOME%/lib/`;
   2.3. restart JMeter.
3. Configure JSR233 Sampler:

   3.1. add JSR233 Sampler to Thread Group;
   3.2. set `Script Language` to `groovy` in sampler's settings;
   3.3. put your selenium test-scenario into `Script` section (Java code will be accepted):

[image]

#### Selenium RC

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Boolean result = true;

try {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://www.google.com/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.windowMaximize();

    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");      

    if (!selenium.isTextPresent("Google")) result = false;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
     SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
     SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
     SampleResult.setResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    selenium.stop();
}

SampleResult.setSuccessful(result);
return result;
```

#### Selenium WebDriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

Boolean result = true;

try {
    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

    if (!driver.getTitle().contains("Google")) result = false;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
     SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
     SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
     SampleResult.setResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    driver.quit();
}

SampleResult.setSuccessful(result);
return result;
```

---

**Common notes for BeanShell / JSR223 Sampler cases:**

- Use external .bsh / .groovy files with test-scenario (`Script file` field) instead of using Beanshell / Groovy code directly in sampler for intensive testing.
- Since  BeanShell / JSR233 Samplers have access to JMeter's variables you can set test (= sampler execution) status directly in test-scenario (via e.g. `IsSuccess = STATUS` or `SampleResult.setSuccessful(STATUS)`, see code above), without using Response Assertion.

Comment: As far as I know with Junit4 one does not have to extend TestCase class and I guess one should not either

Comment: there is a tick box on the sampler to tell it to use junit 4 annotations. If you do not tick, you must respect junit unit test naming conventions and extends in your java class.

Answer (score 8):

There is easier way to run Selenium scripts.

1. Download [WebDriver plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) and move to lib/ folder.
2. Add jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config and jp@gc - Web Driver Sampler to your test tree

[image: Jmeter test tree]

- Add this code

  ```
      var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
      var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
      var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)
      WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
      WDS.log.info("Opening page...");
      WDS.browser.get('http://duckduckgo.com')
      var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_form_input_homepage'))
      searchField.click()
      WDS.log.info("Clicked search field")
      searchField.sendKeys(['blazemeter'])
      WDS.log.info("Inserted blazemeter keyword")
      var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('search_button_homepage'))
      button.click()
      WDS.log.info("Clicked search button");
      var link = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.ByCssSelector('#r1-0 > div.links_main > h2 > a.large > b'))
      link.click()
      WDS.log.info("Clicked blazemeter link");
      WDS.log.info(WDS.name + ' finishing...');
      WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
  ```
- Run your test

For more detailed information about code syntax and best practises you can try [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) article.

Comment: I tried this and it works.  I'm not a huge fan of coding Selenium in Javascript, but at least it works.  If I ever find a Groovy or a java alternative method I will definitely go with that though.

Comment: It didn't work I am not able to see the results in the view results tree.

Answer (score 3):

There should not be a need to use Selenium with JMeter. Selenium script will take one instance of a browser at a time. Whereas, JMeter does not use a real instance of a browser to generate load.

Please let me know if Selenium script can be used to generate a load from UI standpoint for 5000 vusers. It probably can. But then are we saying that the Selenium script would now require 5000 instances of a browser on the same system? Will the test still run or hang the system instead? JMeter already has great options as a Recorder as well. It provides great stats from "load" testing standpoint.

For a moment if we think that users who know Selenium won't know how to script in JMeter and hence a learning curve. But in case of JMeter this is even not true. It's because there is no need to create something like a logical sequence or a program in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you record your script with selenium first and then re-record the selenium test cases using jmeter. :-)

http://codenaut.blogspot.com/2011/06/icefaces-load-testing.html

Comment: For anything beyond a simple no-authentication webpage, jmeter recording is insufficient, the bigger chunk of work will be handing auth tokens and other dynamic values correctly. The question really is asking how you can run existing selenium scripts rather than how to create jmeter scripts.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer did work for me perfectly, **Selenium RC** is outdated. So here's the updated [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) approach.

**NOTE** : The setup can be re-used from the accepted answer.

### JUnit Request Sampler (Jupiter Test code)

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SimpleGoogleSearch extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testSelenium() {

        // Replace the following line with the path to your chromedriver.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "path to your chrome driver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class = 'gLFyf gsfi']"));
        searchField.sendKeys("google");
        searchField.submit();
        assertEquals("google - Google Search", driver.getTitle());
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

[image: JUnit Sampler]

### JSR223 Sampler + Groovy

[image]