# steps for recording the selenium events on jmeter proxy

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am presently working on a project for which selenium scripts are prepared and i want my jmeter proxy should record the steps executed by selenium browser. I tried running selenium and jmeter proxy server on same port but while doing that  proxy server of jmeter refuse to start on same port. I read somewhere that this is possible but i am not getting the steps needs to follow.

Comment: Are you using Selenium RC or Selenium 2 WebDriver?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

You should do the same what you will do for simple test recording through Jmeter proxy:

1. setup Jmeter HTTP Proxy Server;
2. start configured Jmeter Proxy;
3. configure and enable proxy settings in your test browser (used by selenium) to use Jmeter Proxy.

Then run your selenium tests as usual, via configured test browser - HTTP Proxy Server will record execution.

To exclude all the steps performed in the "selenium-server" window try to add the following to 'URL Patterns to Exclude' in HTTP Proxy Server settings:

```
^/selenium-server/.*
```

Useful point here is to separate recorded execution into different Thread Groups - e.g. separate Thread Group in Jmeter for each recorded selenium testcase.

Step-by-step guideline you may found [here](http://lukaszbudnik.blogspot.com/2008/10/web-application-testing-with-selenium.html).

To tell the truth such the "re-recording" may appear not very useful and effective: JMeter is not a browser, and does not interpret the JavaScript in downloaded pages.

As per [Jmeter wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ#Does_JMeter_process_dynamic_pages_.28e.g._Javascript_and_applets.29):

> JMeter does not process Javascript or applets embedded in HTML pages.
>
> JMeter can download the relevant resources (some embedded resources
>   are downloaded automatically if the correct options are set), but it
>   does not process the HTML and execute any Javascript functions.
>
> If the page uses Javascript to build up a URL or submit a form, you
>   can use the Proxy Recording facility to create the necessary sampler.
>   If this is not possible, then manual inspection of the code may be
>   needed to determine what the Javascript is doing.

So if you need Jmeter possibilities to implement load/performance-testing based on existent Selenium functional scripts better for you then use [run Selenium scripts from Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817498/running-selenium-scripts-from-jmeter).

Comment: Alies, seems broken link on step by step guideline

Comment: @eugene.polschikov Seems that blog moved to another address. Fixed. Thank you.