# Use perl Selenium test scripts for performance testing in jmeter

Tags: perl, selenium, webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I have selenium web driver test scripts written in perl. Now i want to use them for performance testing with jmeter.

Can any one help me how can i use it for performance testing?

I tried few solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817498/running-selenium-scripts-from-jmeter/7823777#7823777) but no use because my tests are in perl.