# How can i use my Junit test (selenium webdriver) with Jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter, junit4

I created my functional tests with JUnit 4 and Selenium Webdriver and it works.
Now I want to use this test with JMeter for performance tests.

I copied `selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar` at JMeter’s library, then I exported my test from Eclipse to .jar file.

And this my selenium test

```
public class TestLoginWithFF {   
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/pages/accueil/login.xhtml#loaded");

    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }   
  } 
}
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/18350556/2586371 solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some sort of scenario recorder. I know that [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org) provides such feature. JMeter should have it to.

The idea is to execute your tests through the recorder so that they'll be recorded in JMeter language, ready to be used.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean !

Comment: You can use [JMeter proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).

The idea is to execute your selenium tests on your browser configured to use the JMeter proxy. This way, when the tests execute, all the requests will be saved by JMeter Proxy, and you're done ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can now use webdriver natively in JMeter with a plugin:
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment out this line; then JMeter will know your method.