# I already have my web application script at place using selenium webDriver ,how can i integrate that with jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have my web Application automation script using Selenium WebDriver,i want to use it with jmeter for Performance testing of my application

*I have tried using Webdriver sampler(as i cannot use my code with this ) and Junit Request sampler

Kindly Suggest some better way to integrate and monitor it

Comment: Please select the languages as Java in the web driver sampler and try to execute the selenium script. I have not tried; just giving my thoughts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Selenium scripts with JMeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817498/running-selenium-scripts-with-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to reuse your Selenium tests for conducting the load test as browsers (even headless like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)) are very CPU intensive and have huge memory footprint so most likely you won't be able to kick off the required number of browsers.

I would recommend converting your Selenium tests into "pure" JMeter HTTP-protocol based load tests, this way you will be able to simulate hundreds of virtual users form mid-level laptop.

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Configure your Selenium test [to use JMeter as a proxy](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)
3. Run your test
4. Perform correlation and parameterization if required
5. You should be ready to use JMeter test for load testing

You may also be interested in [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) article which describes an alternative way of conversion.