# jMeter - Selenium integration

Tags: selenium, jmeter, integration

I have jMeter test case already written, it has requests for logging in and some POST requests to my table. 
Now I want to measure render time of the page (response of the POSTS).
I want to use Selenium so I read: 
[Running Selenium scripts with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817498/running-selenium-scripts-with-jmeter)

The problem is that i want Selenium to use the same session (in other words: to be already logged in) as logging in was handled by jMeter already.
How can i archive that ?

My TestPlan:

[image]

[UPDATE]
@Dmitri T

Thanks for answer! I did what you have suggested but it still don't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong but still just after Selenium opens browser it goes to login page. I put JSR223 PostProcessor under my LOGIN POST request and this is my WebDriver Sampler:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium);
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait);
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); 
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

WDS.browser.get(WDS.parameters);
WDS.log.info("LOGGING INTO: " + (WDS.parameters))

var cookieManager = WDS.vars.getObject('cookieManager')

for (var i=0; i < cookieManager.getCookieCount(); i++) {
    var jmeterCookie = cookieManager.getCookies().get(i)
    var seleniumCookie =  new org.openqa.selenium.Cookie(jmeterCookie.name, jmeterCookie.value, jmeterCookie.domain, jmeterCookie.path, java.util.Date.from(java.   time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(jmeterCookie.expiresMillis)), jmeterCookie.secure)
    WDS.browser.manage().addCookie(seleniumCookie)
}

java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

[image]

{UPDATE 2}

Ok, i think that htere is something wrong with Cookies in all Thread Group.
I have [no cookies] on every request:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the "session" you need to copy all the cookies from JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) into the Selenium session.

This can be done in the WebDriver Sampler directly as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which session you want to copy
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   vars.putObject('cookieManager', sampler.getCookieManager())
   ```

   it will store the current state of the HTTP Cookie Manager into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. In the WebDriver Sampler you can copy the cookies from the HTTP Cookie Manager and add them to the WebDriver instance using [WDS.browser.manage().addCookie()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#addCookie-org.openqa.selenium.Cookie-) function as follows:

   ```
   var cookieManager = WDS.vars.getObject('cookieManager')

   for (var i=0; i < cookieManager.getCookieCount(); i++) {
       var jmeterCookie = cookieManager.getCookies().get(i)
       var seleniumCookie =  new org.openqa.selenium.Cookie(jmeterCookie.name, jmeterCookie.value, jmeterCookie.domain, jmeterCookie.path, java.util.Date.from(java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(jmeterCookie.expiresMillis)), jmeterCookie.secure)
       WDS.browser.manage().addCookie(seleniumCookie)
   }
   ```